# Creating a C# method that makes a windows form responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, responsive

So I'm creating a c# method that can make a c# form responsive.
In the proof of concept where the control variables were hard coded(on form load I assigned the control bounds to a rectangle variable), this method worked but it was not reusable as a developer would've needed to hard code all control variables.

So my solution add the controls on form load to a list:

Form Load Event:

```
List<Control> controlList = new List<Control>();

foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            controlList.Add(control);
        }
```

But this list doesn't save the size and location values as needed by the resize method. How can I add the size and location values to the list? or is there a better way to do this? Without having the initial size and location of the controls the form does not resize correctly.

Resize Event:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle originalControlRect;
        float originalControlFontSize;
        foreach (Control control in controlList)
        {
            originalControlRect = new Rectangle(control.Location, control.Size);
            originalControlFontSize = control.Font.Size;
            ResizeFunction(control, originalControlRect, originalControlFontSize);
        }
    }
```

Resize Method:

```
private void ResizeFunction(Control control, Rectangle originalControlRect, float originalControlFontSize)
    {
        //calculate the new size of the control
        float xRatio = (float)this.ClientRectangle.Width / (float)originalFormRect.Width;
        float yRatio = (float)this.ClientRectangle.Height / (float)originalFormRect.Height;

        //calculate the new location of the control
        float newX = (float)originalControlRect.Location.X * xRatio;
        float newY = (float)originalControlRect.Location.Y * yRatio;

        //set the new size and location of the control
        control.Location = new Point((int)newX, (int)newY);
        control.Width = (int)(originalControlRect.Width * xRatio);
        control.Height = (int)(originalControlRect.Height * yRatio);

        //set the new font size of the control
        float ratio = xRatio;
            if (xRatio >= yRatio)
            {
                ratio = yRatio;
            }

        float newFontSize = originalControlFontSize * ratio;
        Font newFont = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, newFontSize);
        control.Font = newFont;
    }
```

I added all the code here as there isn't much about this topic online.

Comment: Is the code in your form load event being called before or after `InitializeComponent();`? If it's before, `Controls` contains no objects as far as I know, you need to populate that list after the component is initialized

Comment: After, the list gets populated with the controls but not with the size and location values

Comment: Are the `Size` and `Location` properties themselves set to `null` or are the `X`, `Y`, etc, values of those properties all set to 0?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Control.ScaleControl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.scalecontrol) method and the underlying code that perform that calculation: [ScaleControl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,11480), [ScaleSize](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,11621) and [ScaleCore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,11576)